# How to use the same trigger function for insert/update/delete triggers avoiding the problem with new and old objects

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, postgresql-triggers

I am looking for an elegant solution to this situation:

- I have created a trigger function that updates the table `supply` with the sum of some detail rows, whenever a row is inserted or updated on `warehouse_supplies`.
- PostgreSQL `insert or update` syntax allowed me to share the same function `sync_supply_stock()` for the insert and update conditions.
- However, when I try to wire the `after delete` condition to the function it cannot be reused (although it is logically valid), for the returning object must be `old` instead of `new`.

```sql
-- The function I want to use for the 3 conditions (insert, update, delete)
create or replace function sync_supply_stock ()
returns trigger
as $$
begin
    -- update the supply whose stock just changed in warehouse_supply with
    -- the sum its stocks on all the warehouses.
    update supply 
    set stock = (select sum(stock) from warehouse_supplies where supply_id = new.supply_id)
    where supply_id = new.supply_id;
    
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- The (probably) unnecessary copy of the previous function, this time returning old.
create or replace function sync_supply_stock2 ()
returns trigger
as $$
begin
    -- update the supply whose stock just changed in warehouse_supply with
    -- the sum its stocks on all the warehouses.
    update supply 
    set stock = (select sum(stock) from warehouse_supplies where supply_id = old.supply_id)
    where supply_id = old.supply_id;
    
    return old;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- The after insert/update trigger
create trigger on_warehouse_supplies__after_upsert after insert or update
on warehouse_supplies for each row 
execute procedure sync_supply_stock ();

-- The after delete trigger
create trigger on_warehouse_supplies__after_delete after delete
on warehouse_supplies for each row 
execute procedure sync_supply_stock2 ();
```

Am I missing something or is there any fixing to duplicating `sync_supply_stock2()` as `sync_supply_stock2()`?

---

EDIT

For the benefit of future readers, following @bergi answer and discusion, this is a possible factorized solution

```sql
create or replace function sync_supply_stock ()
returns trigger
as $$
declare
    _supply_id int;
begin
    -- read the supply_id column from `new` on insert/update conditions and from `old` on delete conditions
    _supply_id = coalesce(new.supply_id, old.supply_id);
    
    -- update the supply whose stock just changed in of_warehouse_supply with
    -- the sum its stocks on all the warehouses.
    update of_supply 
    set stock = (select sum(stock) from of_warehouse_supplies where supply_id = _supply_id)
    where supply_id = _supply_id;
            
    -- returns `new` on insert/update conditions and `old` on delete conditions 
    return coalesce(new, old);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger on_warehouse_supplies__after_upsert after insert or update
on of_warehouse_supplies for each row 
execute procedure sync_supply_stock ();

create trigger on_warehouse_supplies__after_delete after delete
on of_warehouse_supplies for each row 
execute procedure sync_supply_stock ();
```

Comment: You can use `TG_OP` to distinguish whether your trigger function was called on insert, update or delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for the returning object must be `old` instead of `new`.

No. The return value is only relevant for `BEFORE ROW` or `INSTEAD OF` triggers. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): "*The return value of a row-level trigger fired `AFTER` or a statement-level trigger fired `BEFORE` or `AFTER` is always ignored; it might as well be null*".

So you can just make your `sync_supply_stock` trigger function `RETURN NULL` and it can be used on all operations.

Comment: Hmmm. There is still a problem with new/old. As I use these objects to get `new.supply_id`, the delete condition does not work as the `new` object is null. I will need to switch/case with `tg_op`.

Comment: @coterobarros Ah, I didn't look at that, I thought they were identical. You can use `WHERE supply_id = COALESCE(NEW.supply_id, OLD.supply_id)` for that